# MQTT client disconnect

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm trying to get two mqtt clients to communicate on a mqtt server with the following configurations:

```
listener 1883 
persistence true
connection_messages false
log_timestamp true
allow_anonymous false
```

and this code:
File Pong.py

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
broker = 'ipserver'
pub_topic = "Pong"
sub_topic = "Ping"

def on_connect(client, userdata,flags,rc):
    print("Connesso")
    client.subscribe(sub_topic)

def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
    print(str(msg.payload))
    client.publish(pub_topic, "Pong")

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(broker,1883,60)
client.loop_forever()
```

File Ping.py

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

#broker = "test.mosquitto.org"
broker = 'ipserver'
pub_topic = "Ping"
sub_topic = "Pong"

def on_connect(client, userdata,flags,rc):
    print("Connesso")
    client.subscribe(sub_topic)
    client.publish (pub_topic, "Ping")

def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
    print( msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(3)
    client.publish(pub_topic, "Ping")

def on_publish(mosq,obj,mid):
    print("Ping")

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_publish =on_publish
client.connect(broker,1883,60)
client.loop_forever()
```

The problem is that they repeat the onconnect function in a loop, continuing to reconnect and therefore not communicating with each other

Comment: What do the broker logs show?

Answer (score 2):

You have explicitly told the broker to reject anonymous clients, yet you haven't supplied:

1. A username/password for either client
2. Told the broker how to authenticate clients when they connect.

Change `allow_anonymous false` to `allow_anonymous true`